# How to get the table name that is related to specific schema in sybase IQ

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

My requirement is to use *syscolumn* and *systable* system tables. By using these 2 tables, return the specific table within specific schema. But *systable* is holding same table name from 3 different schemas, how to get the table name with requried schema?

*table_id* is the relation between *syscolumn* and *systable*, but I don't see schema/owner/creator details in both tables.

where can I get the relation of schema to these tables? I did google-ing but no luck.

For this requirement, I can't use *sp_columns*, *sp_tables* procedures..I know we have owner details in these procedures.

Answer (score 3):

```
select u.name, o.name 
from sysusers u, sysobjects o
where u.uid = o.uid 
    and o.type  = 'U'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed